# xUnit with SQLite in memory test

Tags: sqlite, xunit

I want to use SQLite for unit testing and I have noticed that it load the real database data.
The whole databse (fortunatelly it is not so big) is in the context before seeding it.
First I did not understand why it throws a **SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed** error at seeding but than I noticed this wierd thing.

Am I wrong or it is right?

**Update**

It seems to me that SQLite preserves data after debug process is finished.
How can I ensure that SQLite is deleted after each debugging process, please?

**Update**
Oh, the seed method of real db context load data into SQLite in memory database at each time when I run test.

Answer (score 0):

The seed method of real db context load data into SQLite inmemory database at each time when I run test.